# What's the translation of "monogenic system" in French?

Tags: traduction, science

Does somebody know how to translate *monogenic system* in French?

In classical mechanics, a *monogenic system* is a system where all forces, with the exception of the constraint forces, are derivable from the generalized scalar potential, and this generalized scalar potential is a function of generalized coordinates, generalized velocities, or time.

I haven't found any classical mechanics book in French mentioning *monogenic systems*... quite strange...

Comment: Salut Christophe, have you found the word in a dictionary or other general reference source?  What did it give?  This will help us figure out where you're having trouble.  Here's the [help], et bienvenue.

Comment: Hello! It's not yet clear what could be the translation. But at least we've found some hints.

Answer (score 1):

In engineering classes, I heard about "système monogénique". However, I am not sure if that is correct or not ... Very often some professors would translate one to one, either using monogenic systems or the French translation even though it does not exist.

Comment: Strange --- the internet seems to apply "monogénique" more to biology.

Comment: In fact, this is what I read too. But I heard it only once, and I cannot find any other related answer. Therefore, I would suggest keeping the English way of saying it. In French it could turn out to be monogenic systems, basically English vocabulary but using French grammar ... !

Comment: @Frank  It seems logical since according *monogénique* refers only to [genes](https://dictionnaire.lerobert.com/definition/monogenique) in French. Whereas it seems that the English [monogenic](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/monogenic) has a broader acceptance. Nevertheless I've found [this thesis](https://theses.hal.science/tel-00462403/preview/2009_Vorms.pdf) see p. 81. It does seem to be about mechanics but I haven't done any science studies so I'll leave to whoever understands.

Comment: @None The relevant passage from that thesis seems to be: "Dans la terminologie adoptée par Lanczos (1970, p. 30), les forces dérivant d'un potentiel, qu'elles soient conservatives ou non, sont appelées monogéniques ; les forces qui ne dérivent pas d'un potentiel (comme par exemple les forces de frottement), sont dites polygéniques."

Comment: @Frank J'avais trouvé ça:  « Le principe s'étend aussi aux systèmes monogéniques non conservatifs, ainsi qu'à certains systèmes qui ne sont pas à strictement parler monogéniques »  mais je redis que je ne comprends pas ! Je peux juste apercevoir qu'il s'agit de physique ou de maths.

Comment: @None Oui, c'est aussi un bon passage, encore plus proche de la question. Il semblerait donc qu'on puisse bien traduire par "système monogénique", avec le caveat que cette terminologie est apparemment spécifique à un auteur (Lanczos).

Comment: Merci pour tous vos commentaires. Sur la page suivante, on parle de fonctions monogènes en mathématiques. Cette propriété est en relation avec la dérivabilité, ce qui peut être en relation avec la mécanique, vu que les forces dérivent d’un potentiel (on dérive le potentiel pour en obtenir la force). Il semble néanmoins que cet adjectif de « monogène » est relativement vieux. (Lien: https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Monogenic_function)

Comment: @Christophe Je m'aperçois que sur Wikipedia [Monogenic system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monogenic_system) n'a pas d'article correspondant en français. Alors moi qui ne parle pas le langage mathématique je me demande comment quelqu'un qui fait des études de maths ou de physique en français appelle ce qui est décrit dans cet article en anglais, bref, je reviens à ta question !!

Comment: J'ai trouvé plusieurs références sur les fonctions monogènes en mathématiques (dans le domaine de l'analyse complexe) et la traduction en anglais est "monogenic functions". Par contre je n'arrive pas à trouver si il existe un lien entre un "monogenic system" en mécanique et une "monogenic function" en mathématiques. Le point commun est la notion de dérivabilité, mais je ne suis pas encore convaincu.